# Restoring Lost Messages

Tags: google-pixel-6, google-messages

I wasn't paying attention to what I was doing while using Messages for Web and instead of typing in a new message to my wife, I did *something* to cause our whole 5 year long conversation thread to disappear. (I say 'disappear' than 'deleted' for reasons I'll describe below.)

Since I was on Messages for Web, I quickly hopped on my phone. Nope, gone there too. I checked the Archive. Not there. So I started Googling. Most sites said that if texts are deleted, then they're gone for good, but I did find [this](https://support.google.com/pixelphone/thread/222817273/restore-deleted-messages?hl=en) that says to use the app *SMS Backup and Restore* to check if the messages are truly gone.

So I download the app and lo and behold, the entire conversation is there! I successfully create a backup of the entire conversation! I can see the messages in the xml file that is generated and I have it stored in triplicate on my phone, my Google Drive, and my desktop.

The problem now lies in restoring the messages. When I try to use *SMS Backup and Restore*'s restore feature, it runs, but at conclusion says that all ~30000 items are duplicates and that nothing was restored.

This leads to my question: How can I restore these messages - either using *SMS Back and Restore*, or by some other method, since they clearly still exist on the phone in some unknown location.

Comment: check the xml file for 'deleted' flags. or, as the link says, messages just lost track to conversation. in that case clear app data and import backup again.